# Where can I find list of Rider IDE commands to use in _ideavimrc file?

Tags: c#, ide, rider, ideavim

Wanted to create a _ideavimrc file but I cannot find the commands that Rider uses.

Such list exists in VisualStudio under `Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard` .
Example command being: `Build.BuildSolution`. Then I could use it in my _vsvimrc file (for VsVim).

But I cannot find such a list on Rider.

Answer (score 0):

Following this blog [post](https://amine-elhattami.medium.com/destination-ideavim-day-1-the-basics-793a514af57f) :

> There are two ways to find the action ids.
> First, while in normal mode in the editor, type:
>
> `:actionlist`
>
> This will show the full list of action ids.
>
> However, it’s hard to find what you’re looking for this way.
>
> This is why I like the second method.
> From the action menu enable `IdeaVim: Track Action Ids`.
>
> Then using your mouse (I know, just for this time), use the feature you want. > Finally, you will find the name of the action in the `Event Log`.